# C# NullReferenceException Error

Tags: c#, groupbox

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Prototype
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        object oDocument;
        int thmbNailCnt = 0;
        GroupBox[] thmbNail = new GroupBox[100];
        PictureBox[] picBox = new PictureBox[100];
        TextBox[] texBox = new TextBox[100];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void addWordToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void scheduleToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Office Documents " + " " + "(*.doc, *.docx)|*.doc;*.docx";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document;
            string sFileName;
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            if (sFileName.Length != 0)
            {
                oDocument = null;
                webBrowser1.Navigate(sFileName);
                document = webBrowser1.Document;
                newThumbNail(1, sFileName);
            }
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            oDocument = webBrowser1.Document;

        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Office Documents " + " " + "(*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document;
            string sFileName;
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            if (sFileName.Length != 0)
            {
                oDocument = null;
                webBrowser1.Navigate(sFileName);
                document = webBrowser1.Document;

            }
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Office Documents " + " " + "(*.ppt, *.pptx)|*.ppt;*.pptx";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document;
            string sFileName;
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            if (sFileName.Length != 0)
            {
                oDocument = null;
                webBrowser1.Navigate(sFileName);
                document = webBrowser1.Document;

            }
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Office Documents " + " " + "(*.pdf)|*.pdf";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document;
            string sFileName;
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            if (sFileName.Length != 0)
            {
                oDocument = null;
                webBrowser1.Navigate(sFileName);
                document = webBrowser1.Document;

            }
        }

        private void newThumbNail(int docType, string fileName)
        {




            thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Visible = true;            
            thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Location = new Point(2, 5);
            thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Size = new Size(222, 50);


            picBox[thmbNailCnt].Parent = thmbNail[thmbNailCnt];
            picBox[thmbNailCnt].Visible = true;
            picBox[thmbNailCnt].Location = new Point(6, 13);
            picBox[thmbNailCnt].Size = new Size(31, 31);
            picBox[thmbNailCnt].Image = new Bitmap("images/excel.png");

            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Parent = thmbNail[thmbNailCnt];
            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Visible = true;
            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Location = new Point(53, 24);
            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Size = new Size(163, 20);
            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Text = fileName;
            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Enabled = false;

            this.Controls.Add(thmbNail[thmbNailCnt]);
            this.Controls.Add(picBox[thmbNailCnt]);
            this.Controls.Add(texBox[thmbNailCnt]);


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



    }
}
```

My program throws a null reference error whenever it enters the function private void newThumbNail(int docType, string fileName). Please Help. I believe I have declared the groupBox, textBox, and picture Box properly. But I'm not sure if I have declared a valid array of groupBox.

Comment: null reference exception? never heard of it...

Comment: place a breakpoint inside it, step and look the value of thmbNail, then the value of thmbNail[thmbNailCnt], try to understand what is null, debugging with visual studio is faster than try other to guess where the error is

Answer (score 3):

You've declared arrays and created them, so your arrays are indeed not the cause of the NRE.  However, what are the arrays filled with?  Where do you specify that the contents of the arrays have non-null values?  For example, you need something along the lines of:

```
thmbNail[0] = new GroupBox(...)
```

Possibly you are expecting arrays to auto expand when you add to the end.  C# doesn't support that with arrays, so you'd be better off using a `List<GroupBox>` instead of a `GroupBox[]`.

Comment: What I would like to do is to create an array of groupTextBox. Could you teach me how to do it?

Comment: @user, you've already created the array.  What you haven't done is instantiate any of the elements.  In other words, your array is just an array of nulls at present.  You could consider adding this line  `thmbNail[thmbNailCnt] = new GroupBox();` to the beginning of `newThumbNail`.  But that will only fix the first arary.  You'll have to do similar for the others.

Answer (score 2):

You declare thmbNail and give it a length, but you have not populated any of its elements.  So `thmbNail[thmbNailCnt]` returns a null value, which then throws the NullReferenceException when you try to access its `Visible` property.  Perhaps you should assign a new value into it first:

```
if (thmbNail[thmbNailCnt] == null)
    thmbNail[thmbNailCnt] = new GroupBox();
thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Visible = true;
```

You'll have the same issue with the picBox and texBox arrays.  Also remember to add them to your form when created.

Comment: I really prefer don't see such a code in a real world app. thmbNail array come from code written some lines before, we know what is null or not, so *no reasons* for 'ifs'

Comment: It's okay, it's for academia, they have much lower standards. Insert Frown emoticon here.

Comment: I agree.  Initially, I thought he was trying to populate the entries in the array in no particular order.  But on a second look at the code, it looks more like he wants to simply add a new thumbnail altogether, so Lists should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

All you've done is declare an array of controls.

```
GroupBox[] thmbNail = new GroupBox[100];
```

To use one you need to instantiate it e.g.

```
GroupBox[thmbnailcount] = new GroupBox();
```

Same for picbox and text box.

No different to doing

```
GroupBox myGroupBox;
```

All you've done is tell the compiler the type of variable. It's not a value type so you have to get a new in there before you try and use it.